# Find $4\int_{0.5}^{1} \int_{0.5}^{1} (xy) dx dy $

Tags: integration

Find:

$I=4\int_{0.5}^{1} \int_{0.5}^{1}  (xy) dx dy $

I think because The first and second integral from $0.5$ to $1$, so

$I =4[{{1} \over {4}} x^2 y^2]_{0.5}^{1}$

but my question, any answer true, i or ii ?

(i) $4[{{1} \over {4}} x^2 y^2]_{0.5}^{1}=1-{(0.5)}^2 {(0.5)}^2= {{15} \over {16}}$

or

(ii) $4[{{1} \over {4}} x^2 y^2]_{0.5}^{1}=[(1-{(0.5)}^2) y^2]_{0.5}^{1}=[(1-{(0.5)}^2)(1-{(0.5)}^2)]={{9} \over {16}} $ ?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4):

Recall that the way to evaluate double integrals is inside out, not all at once. Hence we have $$4\int _{0.5}^1\int_{0.5}^1 xy dx dy = 4\int_{0.5}^1 \frac{1}{2}x^2y|_{0.5}^1dy = 2\int_{0.5}^1\frac{3}{4}ydy= \frac{9}{16}$$

So (ii) is the correct answer. More or less. This will only give you the right answer for constant bounds, so it is better to just integrate using the above method which always works.

Answer (score 2):

Your second solution is correct. First one integral solved and we put limit values. Then second integration and limit values filled.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is correct, the evaluation is actually $$I=4\int_{0.5}^{1}y\int_{0.5}^{1}x\text{d}x\text{d}y=4\int_{0.5}^{1}y\left.\frac{x^2}{2}\right\vert_{0.5}^{1}\text{d}y=\frac{3}{2}\int_{0.5}^{1}y\text{d}y=\frac{3}{2}\left.\frac{y^2}{2}\right\vert_{0.5}^{1}=\frac{9}{16}$$